# Get content based on taxonomy

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views, blocks

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong, as my block isn't showing up with the content from the taxonomy.
I am trying to create a block that shows the content based on the taxonomy; I made a path on the taxonomy, and the main content shows up, but when I try to add a block using Views, it never shows.

This is the settings page for the taxonomy.

[image: screenshot #1]

This is the view I am using with the argument.

[image: screenshot #2]

**Edit**: I fixed the issue; all I had to do was create a new content and it worked. I guess my only question now is how to keep the block on the front page after adding the filter.

Comment: To which Drupal version are you interested?

Comment: the version this is for is drupal 7

Comment: Can you link to a pastebin of your view export?

Comment: I'm trying to figure this one out myself... Could you post your exported view as an export below? I've been banging my head against a wall for hours on this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the way I did was i used global:null as the contexual filter and then selected provide default value and then went to type: taxonomy term ID from URL and added it in and then added content: has taxonomy term ID and gave it the same settings as the global:null and saved the view, now the reason why i didnt see it is because you have to add new content, for some reason it doesnt pick up the current content with taxonomies

Comment: You should also accept your own answers, so that others see that this question is resolved. And you might want to provide an export of your view.